# Auto populate Customer Id field before save in Serenity Platform

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

I am doing project using **serenity platform** and I have this scenario. I want to auto populate customer id field before save. It will contain 3 letter prefix "CUS" + auto increment number which will be the max Id from customer table + 1. Any idea how i can implement this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I guess one of auto increment field doesn't problem for you. And you can use second computed field like CUS + AutoIncrementIdField. Then use this computed field as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

your approach to calculate the next ID is very dangerous if more than one user will be using your project concurrently.

Why not doing this in the AfterSave overridable method in xyzRepository.cs. There you have read access to the just generated correct ID for this new record. And there you can do a direct update to this new record, setting the "CUSxyz" value.

Regards,

John